# Apache Alias + Rewrite: How to change absolute path of aliased folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have a website that I need to move to a subdirectory.

```
Alias /oldsite /home/server/public_html/oldsite
```

My question is, is there a way to rewrite all of the requests for absolute paths from the root to the new directory?

For example:

```
<img src="/images/test.png">
```

will become:

```
<img src="/oldsite/images/test.png">
```

Is there a way to do this with mod_rewrite?

Thanks and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oldsite/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oldsite/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oldsite/$1 [L]
```

If that starts with mess with whatever site you happen to have in your document root, you could try checking the referer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /oldsite/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oldsite/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/oldsite/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oldsite/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will take a look in a bit. :)